# Join Unrelated tables in Mssql

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, left-join

I have been tasked with recreating views from an oracle 11g database to a MSSQL 2008 database. I got stuck in recreating this view: In oracle it is like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TRANSACTION_VIEW 
(FCT_TM_SOL_ID, FCT_TM_ACID, FCT_TM_RCRE_USER_ID, FCT_TM_TRAN_TYPE, 
FCT_TM_TRAN_SUB_TYPE,DA_SCHM_CODE,DC_GENDER,DC_CUST_TYPE_CODE,DA_ACCT_MGR_ID 
) 
AS 
SELECT  FCT_TM_SOL_ID,FCT_TM_ACID 
,FCT_TM_RCRE_USER_ID,FCT_TM_TRAN_TYPE,FCT_TM_TRAN_SUB_TYPE,dim_account.DA_SC 
HM_CODE, 
DC_GENDER,DC_CUST_TYPE_CODE,DA_ACCT_MGR_ID 
FROM FACT_TRANSACTION ,dim_account,dim_customer 
WHERE  FCT_TM_ACID = dim_account.DA_ACID(+) 
and dim_account.DA_CUST_ID =  dim_customer.DC_CUST_ID(+)
and dim_account.DA_ACCT_OWNERSHIP ='C';
```

There is no direct relation between `FACT_TRANSACTION` and `dim_customer` so I got Stuck when recreating the view in MSSQL. So far I have:

```
CREATE  VIEW TRANSACTION_VIEW 
(FCT_TM_SOL_ID, FCT_TM_ACID, FCT_TM_RCRE_USER_ID, FCT_TM_TRAN_TYPE, 
FCT_TM_TRAN_SUB_TYPE,DA_SCHM_CODE,DC_GENDER,DC_CUST_TYPE_CODE,DA_ACCT_MGR_ID 
) 
AS 
SELECT  t1.FCT_TM_SOL_ID,t1.FCT_TM_ACID 
,t1.FCT_TM_RCRE_USER_ID,t1.FCT_TM_TRAN_TYPE,t1.FCT_TM_TRAN_SUB_TYPE,t2.DA_SCHM_CODE, 
t3.DC_GENDER,t3.DC_CUST_TYPE_CODE,t3.DA_ACCT_MGR_ID 
FROM FACT_TRANSACTION t1 
left join dim_account t2 on t1.FCT_TM_ACID = t2.DA_ACID
left join ---STUCK HERE dim_customer t3
where t2.DA_ACCT_OWNERSHIP ='C';
```

Please help on how to join the un-related entities.

Comment: So what's the DA_CUST_ID field? Which table is it from>

Comment: DA_CUST_ID is from `dim_account` t2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While is no direct relation between `FACT_TRANSACTION` and `dim_customer`, they do have common points (albeit different fields) in `dim_account`. So, you can do the second left join between `dim_account` and `dim_customer` as:

```
SELECT  t1.FCT_TM_SOL_ID,t1.FCT_TM_ACID, t1.FCT_TM_RCRE_USER_ID,t1.FCT_TM_TRAN_TYPE,t1.FCT_TM_TRAN_SUB_TYPE,t2.DA_SCHM_CODE, 
t3.DC_GENDER,t3.DC_CUST_TYPE_CODE,t3.DA_ACCT_MGR_ID 
FROM FACT_TRANSACTION t1 
left join dim_account t2 on t1.FCT_TM_ACID = t2.DA_ACID
left join dim_customer t3 on t2.DA_CUST_ID = t3.DC_CUST_ID
where t2.DA_ACCT_OWNERSHIP ='C';
```